# Prove that, there exists no continuous function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Prove that, there exists no continuous function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ almost everywhere.$\textbf(Make\ sure\ that\ your\ proof\ is\ completely\ rigorous)$.

I don't know, which property to use. (It is not allowed to show it with $\epsilon-\delta-criterion$, our last topics were: Lp-Spaces, Radon-Nikodym Theorem, Riesz Representation Theorem,Lipschitz-Functions, Product measures, Fubini Theorem)

but i can't find anything to do with continuity, which of them could be useful ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint1**: if a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a complement with Lebesgue
 measure $0$ then it is dense.

**Hint2**: continuous functions are determined by their values on a dense set.

Comment: what do you mean with ''determined''?.

Comment: If you have continuous functions $f$ and $g$ with $f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)$ for every $x\in A$ then density
of $A$ implies that $f$ and $g$ are the same. Highly one continuous
function can be found taking these values on $A$.

Comment: Let $\iota:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ denote the inclusion.
If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous then so is $f\iota$
and $f\iota\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)=1$ on a dense set. This
leads to $f\iota\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)=1$ on $\left[0,1\right].$
Likewise it can be shown that $f\left(x\right)=0$ on the complement
of $\left[0,1\right]$. Then however $f$ is not continuous and a
contradiction is found.

Answer (score 6):

This is an alternative way to see it:

A function is continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open. Look for example at

$$f^{-1}((\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}))=U$$ Why is $U \neq \emptyset$? What can you say about the measure of $U$?

Comment: measure of $U$ is zero, but $U$ can be also the empty set, can't it?

Comment: @derivative $f$ is continuous so it can't be $0$ at some point and $1$ at a different point without being $\frac{1}{2}$ somewhere in the middle (what is the exact argument)? Also open sets contain a small ball, so the measure can't be zero.

Comment: we had this in the beginning of the course, but i think the exercise must be proven with some density theorem or the topics, which i wrote above.

Comment: @density All this proof requires is knowing the Lesbegue measure of an open set is nonzero (which is clear from the definition of the Lesbegue measure) and the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 4):

When $f(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ almost everywhere then any neighborhood $U:=\ ]{-h},h[\ $ of $0$ contains points $x<0$ with $f(x)=0$ as well as points $x>0$ with $f(x)=1$. Such a function cannot be continuous at $0$.