# There exists no continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the same problem on this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596921/prove-that-there-exists-no-continuous-function-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r/596933#596933). One gave an hint defining an inclusion function. Does someone know what is meant there?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate (especially since you are asking about a proof given there).

Comment: Perhaps this page will be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate I'm sorry but there were no ways to could ask something on the other page...

Comment: "there were no ways to could ask something on the other page" Why is that? Can't you comment?

Comment: No 50pts of reputations are required to do this

Comment: OK. This should come soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the hint to that question said is that if a continuous function is $1$ a.e. on $[0,1]$ then it is $1$ in all of $[0,1] $. And, similarly, if it is $0$ a.e. on $\mathbb R\setminus[0,1] $ it is identically zero there. But this leads to a contradiction, because $\chi_{[0,1]} $ is not continuous.